# Почему `get_chat_members` не возвращает генератор со всеми пользователями?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

С помощью Pyrogram пытаюсь получить id пользователей, которые являются участниками чата, но функция get_chat_members возвращает не всех пользователей, около 5-10 в зависимости от выбранной группы, хотя в чате их гораздо больше. Как мне получить всех пользователей?

```
import os
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.enums import ChatType

def main():
    app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
    app.start()

    chat = "id нужного чата"
    members = app.get_chat_members(chat)
    print(members)

    app.stop()

if name == 'main':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в тех группах что вы пробуете скрыты учасники и вам удается спарсить только администраторов.

Попробуйте на других группах, где вы сами можете увидеть учасников.

Comment: Я пробовал в трех разных группах. Для группы с 238 участниками я получаю все id, для группы с 515 - только 3, а для 1849 - только 10. При этом как обычный пользователь я могу видеть всех участников